# Auto Complete text view does not show suggestions

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext

I have implemented an autocomplete edit text and it does show suggestions, but i want to achieve a different functionality as well.

Right now, i have a String of countries

```
private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
    "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
};
```

and i am calling it in my adapter. now when i start to type any country name, my edit text start showing me suggestions, but

**what i want is:**

Lets say i want to write France 10 times in the edit text so i want my autocomplete edit text to give me suggestion when ever i start typing france it and so on,

but my edit text give me suggestion for only the first word i enter. how can i achieve this, like how can my edit text give me suggestion for every text that i enter?

Answer (score 4):

Check the below code, it will work like if you press a space and type something, you will get the suggestion list:

Xml Layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/macTvInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] { "Belgium",
        "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
    MultiAutoCompleteTextView macTvInput = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.macTvInput);
    macTvInput.setAdapter(adapter);
    macTvInput.setTokenizer(new SpaceTokenizer());
}

private class SpaceTokenizer implements Tokenizer {

            private final char delimiter = ' ';

    public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
        int i = cursor;

        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != delimiter) {
            i--;
        }
        while (i < cursor && text.charAt(i) == delimiter) {
            i++;
        }

        return i;
    }

    public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
        int i = cursor;
        int len = text.length();

        while (i < len) {
            if (text.charAt(i) == delimiter) {
                return i;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }

        return len;
    }

    public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
        int i = text.length();
        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == delimiter) {
            i--;
        }

        return text;

    }

}
}
```

Comment: i have actually already implemented with the spcaeTokenizer, but thank you so much for the code. 1+ for you

Answer (score 0):

Use `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` in your Layout, and implement code like this, here i used to split by `commas`

```
    String[] colors = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.AndroidDesk);

    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.suggestion_textview,colors);

    //autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
    multiAutoComplete = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    // set adapter for the auto complete fields
//  autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
    multiAutoComplete.setAdapter(adapter1);

    // specify the minimum type of characters before drop-down list is shown
    //autoComplete.setThreshold(1);
    multiAutoComplete.setThreshold(2);
    // comma to separate the different colors
    multiAutoComplete.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

Comment: 50% solved. now the only issue left is i want something like EnterTokenizer(), is there something similar to this exists?

Answer (score 0):

Use [MultiAutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html) instead of AutoCompleteTextView

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.autocomplete_7);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         MultiAutoCompleteTextView textView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edit);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
         textView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
 }
```

Sources from : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: 50% solved. now the only issue left is i want something like EnterTokenizer(), is there something similar to this exists?

Comment: you may need to implement a custom string tokenizer. For reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120522/multiautocompletetextview-tokenizer-similar-to-facebook-app