# How to update ArrayList used to store KEY in MultiAutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, textwatcher, multiautocompletetextview

I applied a MultiAutoCompleteTextView in my application. Most of the function may be treat as RECEIVER box of email app. I used a custom adapter with hashMap to store the Name and Id as sources of suggestion. When user click the name suggested (only name will show at suggestion list) the Id will programmatically add in a ID_list(arrayList) for next operation.

The problem is, user may click wrongly or change mind

1) How can I **update** the arrayList(ID_list) when user delete some of the names in MultiAutoCompleteTextView ??

2) How to delete a item (in multiautocompletetextview) with one Backspace click but not one character by on character??

Thank you very much.

Comment: studying the hint.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120522/how-do-i-get-multiautocompletetextview-tokenizer-similar-to-facebook-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I realize the importance of "simplization".

1. Use a TextWatcher to update the arrayList(ID_list);

   inputReceiver.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
           private int noOfCharAdded = 0;
           private int noOfCharDeleted = 0;

   ```
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
               int after) {
           noOfCharAdded = after;
           noOfCharDeleted = count;
       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
               int count) {
           KEY_MAC = null;
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

           if (noOfCharAdded >= 1 && noOfCharDeleted > 1) {
               // just input select and backspace
               System.out.println("just input select and backspace "
                       + receiverList.size());
               receiverList.remove(receiverList.size() - 1);
           }

       }
   });
   ```
2. Use a onClickListener to set the cursor to end of string;

   inputReceiver.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   ```
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           inputReceiver.setSelection(inputReceiver.getText().length());
       }
   });
   ```